# How to find an alternate form of this polynomial (factorize?)

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am trying to find the limit of the function

$$\lim_{t \to 1} {{t^3-2t+1}\over{t^3+t^2-2}}$$

And it obviously evaluates to ${0\over0}$ so at first glance it is *indetermined*.

But I have these two polynomials:

$${t^3-2t+1}$$

And:

$${t^3+t^2-2}$$

So I used Wolfram Alpha to find alternate forms for both, being:

$${(t-1)(t^2+t-1)=t^3-2t+1}$$

And:

$${(t-1)(t^2+2t-2)=t^3+t^2-2}$$

And I have read through many sites describing how to factor polynomials but I just can't find an answer; I think this is the most well explained article I've read: [Simple Polynomial Factoring](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/simpfact.htm).

How do I get to those alternate forms? Is factorization the right way to go?

Comment: Evaluating to $\frac00$ and $\infty$ are different things, while both may be considered undefined among reals. For factoring, you need to get familiar with multiplying and dividing polynomials first, then things like the factor theorem.

Comment: I (think) am familiar with polynomial basic operations (+,-,* and /) but it's how to use them in these cases what I don't have enough practice or experience, but I'll research more into that *factor theorem* you mention, maybe that's the keyword I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To factorise cubics and higher degree polynomials, firstly, note that the constant term of the polynomial must be the product of the roots. For example, for $ax^2+bx+c$, $c$ must be the product of $m$ and $n$ if the quadratic factorises to $(x-n)(x-m)$. With this in mind, the roots must be the plus or minus factors of that constant term. Substitute in these factors as values of your $t$ and check if they result in $0$, if they do it is obviously a root and one can use long division/synthetic division to take out the factor. Continue until you get a quadratic and then you can use the quadratic formula to get the other roots if necessary.

Comment: Please don't hate me, but I'm lost in so many things, may I kindly ask for a step-by-step solution for the specific case I mention above? I'm sure I'll find what I'm looking for by looking at an example using those two cases.

Comment: Nobody will ever hate you for asking for a better explanation! Don't be afraid. He we go:

for $t^3+t^2-2$ the constant term is $-2$ and the factors of $2$ are $1$ and $2$, so we know that possible roots are  $1,2,-1,-2$. Try 1, we get $1^3+1^2-2$=0 so 1 is a root and we can divide out $(t-[1])$. If you tried $-1$ you'd get $-2$ so that's not a root. Neither is $2$ or $-2$, as for $t=2$, you get $10$, and for $-2$ you'd get $-6$. If you don't know how to divide out t-1 I'm afraid you're going to have to look up **algebraic long division** also known as synthetic division. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thank you! It's much clearer now… just another question, what do I get from performing the synthetic division?

Comment: Well, if you divide out $t-1$ from $t^3+2t-2$, that's what you get. In this case, it's that $t^2+2t-2$ you see in the alternate form.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Cancel out the common factor $t-1$ when you take the limit. Note that $t \neq 1$.

Observe that $t = 1$ is a zero of both numerator and denominator, hence a well known "theorem" states that $t-1$ is a factor of both of them and you can use Synthetic division or long division to factorise....

Comment: OP was asking how to factorise, not why one factorises.

Comment: I get the part that if they equate to zero when ${t=1}$, then ${t-1}$ would be a factor, but I don't have an idea of how to use synthetic division (I don't even know how to do a synthetic division).

Comment: You can google the method by typing "synthetic division of polynomials" and it pops up some pages that has some examples.